A special Hamel basis
Every infinite set, in particular every Hamel basis $B$ (that is a $\mathbb Q$-vector space basis for the reals)  can be written as a
disjoint union $B=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x_i,y_i,z_i\}$  of sets of cardinal 3 for some set $I$.   This seems to use Zorn's Lemma. My question: given an irrational number $\alpha$, does there exist such a basis $B$ so that  $x_i,y_i$ and $z_i$ in this decomposition can be chosen so that they are $\mathbb Q$-linearily independent and such that $z_i=\alpha y_i$ for every $i\in I$? This does not work of course if $\alpha$ is rational.

See also related question.

Let $S$ be a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. Then $S$ has cardinality continuum and moreover $S\cup \alpha S$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$. Let $T$ be any subset of $S$ such that $T$ and $S\setminus T$ both have cardinality continuum. $S\cup \alpha T$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, so can be complemented to some Hamel basis $S\cup \alpha T\cup U$. Let $y_i,i\in I$ be an enumeration of elements of $T$ by some set $I$ of cardinality continuum, and $x_i,i\in I$ an enumeration of $(S\setminus T)\cup U$ by the same set. Then $S\cup \alpha T\cup U=\bigcup_{i\in I}\{x_i,y_i,\alpha y_i\}$ is a Hamel basis as desired.

Shouldn't the $\alpha\alpha$-term in the second line be just $\alpha$?

@ray corrected, thanks.
